# React button onClick, why this syntax work, other not work?

Tags: reactjs

I am new `React` student.
Also, Sorry I'm not good at English.

3 days ago, I want to change the `state` of button's value when i click the button.
So, I just simply coding like this.

```
/* SKIP CODE */
const [state, setState] = useState("");
/* SKIP CODE*/
<button onClick={setState("&timespan=PT1H")}>1 hour</button>
/* SKIP CODE*/
```

But It's not work.
So I Googling 3 days, finally I solve it like this.

```
<button onClick={() => {setState("&timespan=PT1H")}}>1 hour</button>
```

but, I don't know why.
Can you explain me soooooooooooo easily?

Comment: You don't need to go far, you have such example in docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-my-function-being-called-every-time-the-component-renders

Comment: thank you. The content is not well engraved in my head because my native language is not English, but I will do my best with Google Translator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
<button onClick={setState("&timespan=PT1H")}>1 hour</button>
```

you are assigning to `onClick` the **result** of `setState("&timespan=PT1H")`, so when the method onClick is dispatched by the button, it doesn't executes any function because it has assigned a value, not a function.

However, in `<button onClick={() => {setState("&timespan=PT1H")}}>1 hour</button>` you're assigning to onClick that **function**, so everytime the method `onClick` is dispatched by the button it executes the function setState.

Answer (score 1):

React on render invokes the function call, hence it is used as variables and invoked on-demand for performance optimisation.

```
const callMe = () => {
  console.log('i am called when the button was clicked not on render');
}

<Button onClick={callMe} />
```

Comment: I saw a lot of similar stuff, but I didn't understand it. I only understood after reading the answer below. I now realize that it was easy to explain. Thank you.

Comment: I think I don't have enough knowledge of React to understand this easy explanation. Thank you again.

Comment: It is simple, you are trying to call `callMe()` directly just like in normal HTML. Where as in react, it does it for you on demand. It invokes `callMe` on click of the button and transforms that to `callMe()`. If you try to use callMe() directly, it keeps on invoking the internal methods. It is closure call then it has to be `callMe()()`;
I cannot explain more unless you dive in to the concepts. One step at a time :)

Answer (score 0):

onClick need a **callback** function, that you need to pass, In your case you are passing an arrow function as a callback, you can also pass a normal function to onClick event.

```
function onBtnClick(){
    //do the action here.
}

<button onClick={onBtnClick}>Click Me!</button>
```

Or you can use an arrow function:

```
const onBtnClick = () => {
    //do the action here.
}

<button onClick={onBtnClick}>Click Me!</button>
```

Or you can pass an arrow function inline.

```
<button onClick={() => { //do the action here }}>Click Me!</button>
```

if your function is returning a single line of code, as in your case, you don't need brackets:

```
<button onClick={() => setState("&timespan=PT1H")}>1 hour</button>
```